# cocos2d: CocosBuilder: How to get positions of keyframes of an animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In my application I want to move an object on a path from point to point (based on some event). I want to extract these positions from cocosbuilder file (.ccbi). So how do I extract positions in an array?

One way would be to put sprites on positions and assign them with variables like:
spr1, spr2 spr3

and take the spr1.position in the code.

Another method would be to make an position-animation in cocos-builder. Now extract these keyframes positions in the code. So my question is: "Is there a way to extract positions from the animation keyframes?"

Comment: It's better to use CocosBuilder effects for a simple startup animation. Even if it's possible it's always better to bind your spr1, ... and change position inside your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works with CocosBuilder 2.1.
Add the following function to CCBAnimationManager class:

```
- (void)enumeratePropertiesForSequence:(NSString*)name Block:(BOOL(^)(CCNode *node, CCBSequenceProperty *seqProp))block
{
    int seqId = [self sequenceIdForSequenceNamed:name];
    if (seqId == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sequence %@ couldn't be found",name);
        return;
    }
    for (NSValue* nodePtr in nodeSequences)
    {
        CCNode* node = [nodePtr pointerValue];

        NSDictionary* seqs = [nodeSequences objectForKey:nodePtr];
        NSDictionary* seqNodeProps = [seqs objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:seqId]];

        // Nodes that have sequence node properties
        for (NSString* propName in seqNodeProps)
        {
            CCBSequenceProperty* seqProp = [seqNodeProps objectForKey:propName];

            if (!block(node, seqProp))
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this enumerator you may access all available properties, e.g. if you are interested just in positions then:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "CCBAnimationManager.h"
#import "CCBSequenceProperty.h"
#import "CCBKeyframe.h"
#import "CCNode+CCBRelativePositioning.h"

@implementation MyClass
-(void)fn
{
    CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;

    BOOL(^block)(CCNode *node, CCBSequenceProperty *seqProp) =
    ^BOOL(CCNode *node, CCBSequenceProperty *seqProp)
    {
        NSLog(@"Node tag %d, Prop name [%@], type %d", node.tag, seqProp.name, seqProp.type);

        for (CCBKeyframe *kf in seqProp.keyframes)
        {
            if ([seqProp.name isEqualToString:@"position"])
            {
                id value = kf.value;

                // Get relative position
                float x = [[value objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                float y = [[value objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                // Get position type
                int type = [[[self.userObject baseValueForNode:node propertyName:seqProp.name] objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

                CGSize containerSize = [self.userObject containerSize:node.parent];

                CGPoint absPos = [node absolutePositionFromRelative:ccp(x,y) type:type parentSize:containerSize propertyName:seqProp.name];

                NSLog(@"--- relative position (%f, %f), type %d, abs position (%f, %f)", x, y, type, absPos.x, absPos.y);
            }
        }

        return YES; // YES to continue, NO to stop enumeration
    };

    [animationManager enumeratePropertiesForSequence:@"MySequence" Block:block];
}

@end
```

And here is how to instantiate MyClass and to call the enumerator:

```
CCNode *myclass = [CCBReader nodeGraphFromFile:@"MyClass.ccbi"];
[myclass fn];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, although I havent done that myself.
If you look into a ccb file, you will notice that it is just an XML file.
And this XML file stores only keyframe information (which keyframe happens when).

There is a well-documented structure of the ccb file [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/master/Documentation/X3.%20CCB%20File%20Format.md).
You might wanna have a look how to get the keyframes info.